# How to use actual evapotranspiration in irrigation scheduling?

Tags: hydrology, remote-sensing, evapotranspiration

I have estimated actual evapotranspiration using the Penman-Monteith method and by using remote sensing data.
I have weekly evapotranspiration images. How to utilize this in irrigation scheduling? How to tell when a crop needs irrigation if only we have evapotranspiration data?